# Como reescrever o array inicial e remover items pela ID na view com smarty?

Tags: php, view, loop, template, compiladores

Estou utilizando a [**biblioteca de renderização de View com Smarty**](http://www.smarty.net/).

Na minha view, tenho uma saída com o array de informações do produto dentro de um foreach:

```
{assign var='remove_products' [712, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 745, 755, 758]}
  {foreach from=$products item=product name=products}
    {if !in_array($product.id_product, $remove_products)}
        {$product.id_product|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        {$product.name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        {$product.legend|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
        <!-- OBS: gostaria de salvar todos os dados acima
                em um novo array e usar a coleção novamente abaixo
        -->
    {/if}
  {/foreach]}  

 <!-- usando a coleção (nova) só que com os itens removidos -->

 {$products}
```

Como poderia fazer isso. Alguém sabe? Tentei fazer isso mas não rolou:

```
   {assign var='remove_products' [712, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 745, 755, 758]}
    {assign var='n_products' []}
    {foreach $products as $key => $value}
        {if !in_array($value.id_product, $remove_products)}
            {$n_products[$key] = $value}   
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
    {$products = $n_products}
```

Comment: Qual smarty é? o primeiro exemplo tem a cara do 2, o outro do 3. precisa mesmo definir o array dentro da view/template?

Comment: O primeiro que estou usando.

Comment: O certo mesmo é evitar ter regras de negócio diretamente nas views. Você não consegue passar o vetor de produtos tratado a partir do controlador?

Comment: Concordo, só que o sistema vai ser migrado em breve, eu preciso reescrever isso agora, só pra resolver um probleminha.

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver realmente usando o smarty 2, não existe um maneira legal de fazer isso, precisa fazer o que não deve, que é utilizar a 'tag' do php dentro do template.

```
{php} 
    $this->assign("remove_products", array(712, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 745, 755, 758)); 
{/php}
```

Baseado em: [How to assign an array within a smarty template file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2244319/1342547)

Comment: Beautiful code is gone away

Answer (score 0):

Consegui solucionar o problema fazendo assim:

```
 {if isset($products)}
    {assign var='remove_products' [712, 716, 717, 718, 719, 720, 745, 755, 758]}
    {assign var='n_products' []}
    {foreach from=$products key=key item=product name=products}
       {if !in_array($product.id_product, $remove_products)}
           {$n_products[$key] = $product}
       {/if}
    {/foreach}
 {$products = $n_products}
{/if}
```